# Prove that there is a unique $v \in V$ for which $\langle v,v_k\rangle=c_k$ for all $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, with fixed basis $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Suppose $\langle u,v\rangle$ is an inner product on $V$. If $c_1,\dots,c_n$ are arbitrary scalars, prove that there is a unique $v\in V$ for which $\langle v,v_k \rangle = c_k$ for all $k$.

I'm not even quite sure if I understand the question properly. How can I get started on this question?

Comment: Perhaps you could get started by considering the example where $V = \mathbb R^n$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the usual inner product.

Comment: @Julie Have you studied/heard of Riesz Representation Theorem?

Comment: Can you solve the question if you assume the basis to be orthonormal?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v = \sum \limits _{k=1} ^n x_k v_k$, with $x_k \in \Bbb R$ being the unknown components of $v$ in the given basis.

Introducing the notation $a_{kl} = \langle v_k, v_l \rangle$, you are told that

$$c_k = \langle v, v_k \rangle = \langle \sum \limits _{l=1} ^n x_l v_l, v_k \rangle = \sum \limits _{l=1} ^n x_l \langle v_l, v_k \rangle = \sum \limits _{l=1} ^n x_l a_{lk} .$$

Writing the above in a more visual form, what you have obtained is

$$\left\{
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 a_{11} + x_2 a_{21} + \dots + x_n a_{n1} = c_1 \\
x_1 a_{12} + x_2 a_{22} + \dots + x_n a_{n2} = c_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_1 a_{1n} + x_2 a_{2n} + \dots + x_n a_{nn} = c_n .
\end{eqnarray}
\right.$$

According to the general theory of systems of linear equations, this system of equations has a *unique* solution if and only if $\det (a_{ij}) \ne 0$.

Assume that $\det (a_{ij}) = 0$. This implies that the rows of the matrix are linearly dependent, which means that there exist the numbers $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \Bbb R$, *not all of them $0$*,  such that $\alpha_1 a_{i1} + \dots + \alpha_n a_{in} = 0 \ \forall i$. Remembering who $a_{ij}$ is, this means that $\alpha_1 \langle v_i, v_1 \rangle + \dots + \alpha_n \langle v_i, v_n \rangle = 0 \ \forall i$ or, by linearity, that $\langle v_i, \sum \limits _{j=1} ^n \alpha_j v_j \rangle = 0 \ \forall i$. Since $\{v_i\}_{i=1, \dots, n}$ is a basis, the previous formula implies that $\langle w, \sum \limits _{j=1} ^n \alpha_j v_j \rangle = 0 \ \forall w$. But an inner product cannot be degenerate (by definition), so necessarily $\sum \limits _{j=1} ^n \alpha_j v_j = 0$, which in turn implies that $\alpha_i = 0 \ \forall i$, which is a contradiction with the assumption that not all of the $\alpha$-s are $0$. Therefore, the rows of the matrix $(a_{ij})$ must be linearly independent, so $\det (a_{ij}) \ne 0$, so the solution $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ exists and is unique, and so will be the vector $v$ constructed from it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Fixed $v$ the scalar product is a linear functional and you get its values on a base...

Answer (score 0):

First, there exists a unique $\;\phi\in V^*\;$ (i.e., a unique linear functional) s.t. $\;\forall\;1\le k\le n\;,\;\;\phi v_k=c_k$

Next, from [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), there exists a unique $\;v\in V\;$ s.t. for all

$$\;u\in V\;,\;\;\phi u=\langle v,u\rangle\;$$

Comment: I haven't learned Riesz Representation Theorem yet, but thank you for having the link above. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following linear system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\langle v,v_1\rangle=c_1\\
....\\
....\\
\langle v, v_n\rangle=c_n
\end{cases}
$$

The matrix associate to it is invertible, since its rows are the vectors $v_k$ which form a basis for $V$. Then there exists a unique solution $v$ for every $c_1,...,c_n$.